# How to adapt WordPress theme to BlogEngine.net

Tags: html, themes, wordpress-theming, blogengine.net

Do you know any guidelines on how to create a new [BlogEngine.net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) theme having source code of a WordPress [theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/strange-little-town)?

Comment: So you have a WordPress theme and now you want to move to BlogEngine?

Comment: that's right, but I don't know html/css at all...

Comment: Looks like you're in for a bit of learning then! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to convert it yourself. Just download the [BlogEngine](http://www.codeplex.com/blogengine/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14988) source and create a new theme, they have 13+ examples on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/blogengine/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14988).

Subversion URL: https://blogengine.svn.codeplex.com/svn

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this post](http://rtur.net/blog/post/2008/04/30/Porting-WordPress-theme-to-BlogEngine.aspx) - it explains in details how to port WordPress theme to BlogEngine